# what does "cast in the sea" mean?

Tags: meaning

Handy said he had been inspired by a chance meeting with a woman on the streets of St. Louis distraught over her husband's absence, who lamented, "My man's got a heart like a rock cast in the sea", a key line of the song.
what does "cast in the sea" mean here?

([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Louis_Blues_(song)) - W. C. Handy, explaining how he came to write the song *Saint Louis Blues*)

Comment: Hi bantandor, did you do a google search for 'cast definition' prior to asking your question? If so, what turned up and how does it help or not help you reach an answer?

Comment: Actually, I did but It did not make sense "[some dimension that I do not occupy]  then I asked the question here

Comment: Could you tell us in what way it didn't make sense?

Comment: some dimension that I do not occupy what does that mean

Comment: I think the best course here would be if you copy/pasted the definition**s** (plural!) you found for *cast* in the dictionary, and then tell us which if those seems to you to make the entire sentence make sense, and then elaborate on why you're still a bit uncertain (and in, why none of the definitions you found is quite satisfying). Make sure to do that directly in the body of your question, by [edit]ing it, rather than leave further comments. You'll get much better answers that way.

Comment: My man's got a heart like a rock some dimension that I do not occupy " does it make sense to you?

Comment: OP actually has undertaken a cursory search, and has run up against an apparently irrelevant (faith-related) use of the same words.  Comments so far focus (sensibly) on the definition of _cast_.  However, OP has been trying (equally sensibly) to unpack the phrase _cast in the sea_, as if that is an idiom.  This whole thing will still come down to interpretation, but let's be clear about the thing being addressed.

Comment: I believe the closest one I came up with is "to throw off or away" for the "cast" is that right?

Comment: "Cast", in this sense, means "throw".  @CaptainCranium - It sounds to me like the definition he found was the computer programming sense.

Comment: Then here is the golden question why a heart like a rock thrown in the see is something special. Because it sinks down and gets wasted? or something else  What should I understand from the whole phrase. by the way thanks for everybody

Comment: @bantandor That is, indeed, the true question! But it's also a matter of private interpretation, to picture that, to contemplate what it means, to wrestle with it, to come to understand what is going through the woman's mind .... that is what it is to enjoy poetry! Or, in this case, lyrics. No matter. There is no *right* answer to what a heart is like when it is like a stone thrown in the sea. But there is *your* answer.

Comment: (Or, if you want me to come down from the ivory tower now, a stone is lifeless and unfeeling, and the sea is cold and wet and lonely, and once something is cast into the sea, it can never be recovered. Such a heart is thus  freezing cold, implacable, alone, and lost forever.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's effectively Lit Crit

Comment: @FumbleFingers fair enough:  to those of us who have the tools, this turns out most interestingly to _resolve_ into literary criticism... but that is not why OP came here. We should not be slamming the door in someone's face just because we have decided that they have sought the wrong kind of advice. If you can't unpack a lyric/poem/play at all then _everything_ about it is a matter of (often historical) usage. Let's be willing to help OP ask better questions. In fact, while I was writing my answer, OP actually edited to explain the source. Let's encourage, not be exclusive.

Comment: @DanBron Humbly... I think we can get closer than 'no right answer' (I have attempted with an Answer).  And in any case, we can help OP (a) take a productive analytical perspective, (b) understand critical literary formalities better, and (c) approach a forum like this with less likelihood of being swatted.

Comment: @Captain Cranium: Bear in mind ELU is for *linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.* OP could easily Google [like a stone thrown in the sea](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22like+a+stone+thrown+in+the+sea%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl) to find another half-a-dozen instances where this simile has been used. And if he can't even understand the *literal* meaning of the words, he should be posting on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). Let's ***not*** encourage people who shouldn't be here in the first place.

Comment: (Also, let's remember that ELU is *not* a "forum". It's a Q&A site.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers You want to _restrict_ this to _established_ 'linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts'...? To forestall potential distraction, perhaps you would like me to declare that I am postgraduately all of those things. I would not dream of demanding your credentials, or anyone else's. The trick in this kind of forum, or swimming pool, or cottage, or whatever you would prefer to call it, is to maintain some standard of access for civilians, such that they will not be simply Gilliamed and warn everyone else against bothering. That is for their benefit and ours.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, and of course this is a forum: individuals make the choice to spend time in this community or not, and can expect to be heard, because what they might hear back could be useful _here_, rather than _there_, where they could have gone instead. You seem to be getting that idea confused with useful or wasteful styles of democracy, and/or assuming some kind of hierarchy.

Comment: @Captain Cranium: I don't make the rules (except insofar as I get one vote, same as everyone else here). That point about *who the site is for* has been in the FAQ since before I signed up over 5 years ago, and it's not likely to change just because *you* disapprove. If anything, the fact that we now have ELL for learners means we can and *should* uphold that position even more strongly. And as to whether SO sites should be treated as "forums", I suggest you take it up with TPTB (but I can assure you, they bankroll these sites, and they will *not* agree with you).

Comment: *Cast in* here means *cast into*.

Comment: Thank you all for your effort to help me to understand how to deal with these kind of words and vocabularies. I read all the discussions and they were very helpful to me. One again, Thanks all :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This centres on *Wikipedia's* (current, 16/03/16) assessment of the jazz number 'St Louis Blues'. A [classic rendition by Betty Smith](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNWs0LsimFs) can be found very easily, and appropriate interpretation seems pretty straightforward from both structure and performance.

The words, 'That man's got a heart like a rock cast in the sea' are crucial to this mournful meditation on a (supposedly potential) lover's emotional distance.

The song is about the narrating woman's sense of isolation.  The lyric variously blames the man's (supposedly stupid) inability to acknowledge the narrator, or another woman's (supposedly unfair) influence over him, or the cold inaccessibility of his heart (like a rock thrown [cast] into the sea).  That is where the narrator makes a kind of uneasy peace with the real-life fact that a woman whom she envies has, basically, snagged the man that she fancied.

The narrator is blaming her feeling of loss on everyone except herself, including the man with (she tells herself) an inaccessible heart that has still (weirdly) managed to take itself somewhere else.  The narrator finds herself bewailing the fact that this man really *is* faithful... but to someone else... and that is really quite annoying...

Simple as that, but beautifully delivered.  Ultimately the writing on the page remains vital and really can be read in isolation, but web-searching the words can take you away from the idea of performance.

Comment: Hooray! Spectacularly impressed by a _downvote_, as the only person willing to take this question seriously and do any actual work on it! Would anyone care to own-up and explain? I am entirely open to constructive advice.

Comment: Downvote wasn't me, I don't think there's anything wrong with your answer and nobody else appears to have attempted an actual answer yet. Have an upvote reset, Commander Cortex!